# Problem with pos: abs child

Tags: css, position, overlay

Firstly, visit this demo:
http://persturesson.com/fileupload/

Click Add files... and then DO NOT upload it.
You'll see a bar that fills the whole browsers width.

What I'm trying to do is to have .progress fill the width of #fileupload.
As you can see it's not working that good since position: absolute makes it fill the whole browser. And I need position: absolute (I think), because I want the text and the icons to overlay .progress

Thoughts?

Comment: please show your relevant code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: seriously...don't use tables for non-table data. study some css guides

Comment: @Petr Sorry, but it's how the demo of the downloaded script is built (http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload). I know tables isn't ideal, but that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `#fileupload` to `position: relative`.